# Pig and Java MR are only allocating one mapper per LZO file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a large amount of data in HDFS in LZO format. I have also indexed the LZO files. When I ran the Java MR Job or Load and process the LZO files using PIG, I see that only one mapper is being used per LZO file (Job completes with out any issues but slow). I have number of mappers configured to 50 in my hadoop config, but when I process LZO files I see only 10 mappers are used (one per lzo file). Is there any other configuration I should turn on?

Software versions:

```
Hadoop 1.0.4
Pig 0.11
```

Thanks.

Comment: what's the size of each file? Which `FileInputFormat` do you use?

Comment: More than 1G. Block size in my config is only 128M. Since I am using PIG, I am assuming that TextInputFormat.

Comment: Actually, Pig will combine some input split by its algorithm. You can write `SET pig.noSplitCombination true;` in the pig script, or use `-Dpig.noSplitCombination=true` in the command line to disable it.

Comment: I'm curious why your MR job has the same behavior of Pig.

Comment: Not sure. I want to find out too...

Answer (score 0):

LZO-compressed text files can not be processed in parallel because they are not splittable (i.e. if you read from an arbitrary point in the file you can't determine how to decompress the following compressed data), and so MapReduce is forced to read such a file in serial with a single mapper.

One way to deal with this is to pre-process the LZO text files to create LZO index files that MapReduce can use to split the text files and so process them in parallel.

A more effective approach is to convert the LZO text files into a splittable binary format such as Avro, Parquet, or SequenceFile. These formats allow various data compression codecs (note that Snappy is now much more popular than LZO), and can also provide other benefits such as fast serialization/deserialization, column pruning, and bundled metadata.

The book "Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" has a lot of information on this topic.